# Visualization problems primefaces with chrome

Tags: html, primefaces

I have a JSF application with primefaces. When I click on a menu item and before the page is displayed correctly I see the components for a moment as follows(Image1):

[image]

finally it shows correctly(Image2):

[image]

(
In this way, I would like to avoid viewing the image 1. Does anyone know how I could get it? I attach the code of my page.

masterLayout.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head>
            <title>Entorno Batch</title>
            <link href="resources/css/estilos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{facesContext.externalContext.sessionMaxInactiveInterval};url=#{request.contextPath}/loginView.xhtml"/>
        </h:head>
            <h:body>
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="130" header="Gestión Procesos Batch" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    <ui:insert name="headerLayout" >
                        <ui:include src="./headerLayout.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="300" header="Opciones" >
                    <ui:insert name="menu" >
                        <ui:include src="./menuOptions.xhtml" />
                    </ui:insert>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

administracionProcesos.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition template="/masterLayout.xhtml"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <p:panel id="panelProcesosBatch" >
                <h:form id="form">
                    <p:panel id="panelFiltros" header="Filtros" style="margin-bottom:20px">
```

...

Comment: Please provide codes not screenshots.. Show some effort on questions so other can try to help you

Comment: And provide a [mcve]... It is **impossible** to help with a question like this. And works in FireFox?

Comment: Excuse me, I thought that with a screenshot would be sufficient.